# StandAlone Spring MVC Test framework

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc-test

I am having difficulties installing the the spring mvc test framework (Standalone) for applications running version of Spring older than 3.2.

The standalone project available on https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc exists only in source code and I am not sure how I should add it to my working project's current build path in order to make it accessible in the test class I am attempting to write.

Is it possible to download it as a .jar lib or are there any specific steps I should take?

Comment: You could download the source code and then create a jar, then put that jar into your build path as normal.  Here are instructions on making a jar: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ofcourse it is possible to download it as a jar:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test/3.2.4.RELEASE

link jar to:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-test/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-test-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar

then you need to add is as library to your project which is different subject ( you probably should take a look what maven is ).